# Отображение переменных объекта в браузере с помощью jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Есть такой сервлет

```
public class BotServlet extends HttpServlet {
private Bot bot;

@Override
public void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) throws ServletException {
    super.init();
    bot = Bot.getInstance();
    bot.setId(1);
    bot.setName("Amigo");
    bot.setSerial("777");
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Enter doGet");

    String action = request.getParameter("action");
    System.out.println(action);
    System.out.println(bot);
    request.setAttribute("bot", bot);
    switch (action == null ? "info" : action) {
        case "update":
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/view/update.jsp").forward(request, response);
            break;
        case "info":
        default:
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/view/bot.jsp").forward(request, response);
            break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Enter doPost");

    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    String action = request.getParameter("action");

    if (action.equals("submit")) {
        bot.setId(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id")));
        bot.setName(request.getParameter("name"));
        bot.setSerial(request.getParameter("serial"));
    }

    request.setAttribute("bot", bot);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/view/bot.jsp").forward(request, response);

}
```

}

Так же есть jsp страницы в которые я передаю объект `bot`. Моя проблема заключается в том что я не могу достать данные (значения переменных) этого объекта. Вот пример как я это делаю в самом jsp.

```html
<jsp:useBean id="bot" scope="request" type="com.javamaster.model.Bot"/>
    <tr>
        <td>ID: ${bot.id} | Name: ${bot.name} | Serial number: ${bot.serial}</td>
        <td><a href="bot?action=update">Update</a></td>
    </tr>
```

А на выходе получаю следующее. Хотя ожидаю что будет ID:1 Name: Amigo и так далее

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Смысл программы такой - 2 jsp в одном я ввожу данные(меняю)  в другом отображается. Сами значения меняются (проверил с помощью консоли), а вот почему не правильно отображается не могу понять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим образом. В maven добавил зависимость

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Так же в `web.xml` добавил следующие строки

```html
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
  version="2.5">
```

Информацию по тому что именно прописывать в `web.xml` нашел тут https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info. Если у кого-то будет такая проблема, ищите по ссылке выше подробности. Все получится!